# XML parsing in Apex

Tags: apex, xml, xmlparsing

I want to get the task Id from the below response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response>
    <task id="56639c84-7f73-4ace-b7ab-a46683ff0e25" registrationTime="2017-06-07T13:46:11Z" statusChangeTime="2017-06-07T13:46:11Z" status="Queued" filesCount="1" credits="10" estimatedProcessingTime="5" />
</response>
```

Anyone help me how can i get the above task id in apex?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you done any research? There are plenty of similar questions that should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Document` and `XmlNode` classes in the `DOM` namespace to parse XML.

```
String xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><response><task id="56639c84-7f73-4ace-b7ab-a46683ff0e25" registrationTime="2017-06-07T13:46:11Z" statusChangeTime="2017-06-07T13:46:11Z" status="Queued" filesCount="1" credits="10" estimatedProcessingTime="5" /></response>';
DOM.Document document = new DOM.Document();
document.load(xml);
String taskId = document.getRootElement()
    .getChildElement('task', null)
    .getAttribute('id', null);
system.debug(taskId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just load the XML into Dom.Document, then you can get the appropriate attributes:

```
Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
doc.load(xmlString);
Dom.XmlNode rootNode = doc.getRootElement(),
  taskNode = rootNode.getChildElement('task',null);
String taskId = taskNode.getAttribute('id',null),
       taskStatus = taskNode.getAttribute('status',null);
DateTime registrationTime = (DateTime)JSON.serialize(taskNode.getAttribute('registrationTime',null), DateTime.class));
Integer filesCount = Integer.valueOf(taskNode.getAttribute('filesCount',null)),
    credits = Integer.valueOf(taskNode.getAttribute('credits',null)),
    estimatedProcessingTime = Integer.valueOf(taskNode.getAttribute('estimatedProcessingTime',null));
```